# Can I specify the file name of an iOS Safari image upload?

Tags: ios, safari, data-transfer

Safari on iOS allows to upload images to websites. However, the file always seems to be named image.jpg. This can be a problem, if the targeted website does not allow renaming uploaded files. Is it possible to make Safari let me choose a name or automatically use some unique name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this unless the website allows it. The uploaded file will use the name of the file that you uploaded, and on iOS this is always `image.jpg`.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Comment: I noticed this issue is fixed in iOS10 Safari, which is good.